# How can I refresh ListView control;

Tags: android

I change the source data of ListView control in the mMessageReceiver, but the ListView control still display old rows,
How can I refresh ListView control in the mMessageReceiver? Thanks!

```
   private ListView lv; 

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        HandleRule.SaveFullRule(PublicPar.SharedRule);
        //I hope to refresh ListView control
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms_main);  

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
              new IntentFilter(PublicPar.LocalBroadcastForRule));

    PublicPar.myContext=getApplicationContext();        
    lv = getListView(); 

        FillListView(); 
}

private void FillListView(){
    Cursor c=HandleRule.GetCursorOfAllRuleMain();       
    String[] cols=new String[] {"name"};
    int[] views=new int[]{R.id.mylisttext};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.sms_simple_list_item_multiple_choice,c,cols,views);
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);    
    SetCheckBoxStatus();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just call `FillListView()`?

Comment: Yes, I can call FillListView(), but I think it's not good code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myAdapter..notifyDataSetChanged();
```

is supposed to refresh your listview.
For more details refer to the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: lv.getAdapter() is ListAdapter, but It don't support notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You mean you can't call myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ? By the way , have you tried calling your method FillListView()?

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter is local var, so I can't call at mMessageReceiver , and more lv.getAdapter() return ListAdapter, but ListAdapter don't support notifyDataSetChanged()!